# Jaxb Xjc: make generated classes subtype of Exception?

Tags: jaxb, xjc

How is it possible to make some xjc generated classes subclasses of a custom Exception, such that you can actually throw them, and processable by the JAXBContext? Often webservices return various faults defined that really should be an exception, but since they aren't you need to wrap them unneccesarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I finally found something! The [Inheritance plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Inheritance-Plugin) is able to make the generated classes inherit from classes or implement additional interfaces.

You need to include something like

```
  <bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='WhateverException']">
    <inheritance:extends>foo.bar.WhateverException</inheritance:extends>
  </bindings>
```

into the binding file and override getStackTrace() to return null such that it doesn't get marshalled.

Unfortunately you might run into trouble with some JAXB implementations (see [Blaise Doughan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13725309/21499)) - I haven't found a workaround for that yet. So you can either use a not quite nonportable solution, or wrap the JAXB objects into Exceptions.

Comment: Note: the Highsource link above no longer works - see https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could create a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) model that extended from `Exception` you wouldn't be able to create a `JAXBContext` from it.  I would recommend wrapping the `Exception` in a domain model that is compatible with JAXB.

**Java Model (Foo)**

Below is a simple Java class that extends `Exception`.

```java
package forum12840627;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo extends Exception {

}
```

**Demo**

The demo code below attempts to creates a `JAXBContext` on the Java model.

```java
package forum12840627;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the exception returned from running the demo code.  The problem is that `Exception` is not a valid JAXB class and JAXB implementations pull in the super classes as it processes the Java model.  (Note:  In your own domain model you can annotate super classes with `@XmlTransient` to prevent them from being processed: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html)

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at java.lang.Exception
        at forum12840627.Foo

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at forum12840627.Demo.main(Demo.java:8)
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

If you are using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) as your JAXB provider then you will not see this exception as classes in the `javax.*` and `java.*` packages are not treated as domain classes.  MOXy is the default JAXB provider in the WebLogic 12c environment or can be configured using a `jaxb.properties` file.

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html

**UPDATE #2**

The latest versions of the JAXB reference implementation appear to handle this use case now as well as MOXy.  My original portability concerns may not be so much of an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are right with plain JDK6. Strangely in our project JAXBContext.newInstance does not throw up (problably because of some XML libraries we include.) So, in our setting you can just override getStackTrace() to return null and then you can successfully marshal and unmarshall the exception. (Perhaps one could also write an XmlAdapter for StacktraceElement to avoid this problem on plain JDK6.) So the question is still out how to make xjc subclass a custom exception type.

Comment: @hstoerr - You may be using MOXy as your JAXB provider (see my update).

Comment: For my current JAXB provider it works anyway, but I do hesitate to use a nonportable solution. Do you see a way to configure an XmlAdapter to StacktraceElement (which just should be ignored) or something else to avoid this problem on plain JDK6? I didn't manage that. :-(

Comment: @hstoerr - I have updated my answer.  It appears as though this use case works in recent versions of the JAXB RI as well as MOXy.  I could't get an `XmlAdapter` solution to work for this use case.